# Formatting Announcement Lists to show body

Tags: 2010

Some site templates like the "Document Workspace" have an Announcements web part at the top of the page.  The format of each item shows the title and a portion of the text contained in the body of the announcement.

I am trying to create the same format in a Publishing site that I am working on.  I created an announcement list and added the List View web part but the body does not show up.  I went through all the settings of the web part in each page and don't see any difference so I want to know how to format it to display the body.

Comment: Did you add the body column to the view being displayed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me, the easiest answer is to use a Data View Web Part (DVWP). You  probably won't really want to show the full body because some of them will be very long. Take a look at my blog post on this:
http://sympmarc.com/2010/07/13/displaying-the-first-n-words-of-announcement-bodies-with-xsl-in-a-dvwp/

Comment: Thanks will do.  However I still would like to know how it does it using the List View part.

Comment: The LVWP is a sealed Web Part and it has its own code for this. I suppose if you wanted to use Reflector or something you could figure out how it works under the hood (not that I'd recommend that).

Answer (score 4):

Choose "summary view" in the web part settings

Answer (score 0):

edit the web part view and make is summary.

Comment: Can you expand to make it clear what you mean? Thanks.